# Infinite series for $e$...

Tags: analysis

How do you prove that $e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$? Here I am assuming $e:=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$. Do you have any good PDF file or booklet available online on this? I do not like how my analysis text handles this...

Comment: Just use Taylor series on $e^x$ and put in $x=1$

Comment: how does your text handle it?

Comment: @D.R.: Taylor doesn't follow from the given definition, does it ?

Comment: You can use a binomial expansion on $(1+1/n)^n$ (at least for integer $n$), then note that the terms of this expansion tend (at least pointwise) to the desired sum. (I think they converge monotonically, which would give the desired equality, but I'm not 100% sure of that without doing out the calculation)

Comment: Multiple ways, with trig, with the limit definition, etc.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: yes, that works.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Indeed, each term is positive and increasing, and the number of terms increases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First prove by the ratio test that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$ converges and denote the sum by $S$.

Then note that

$$\begin{align*}
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n & = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \cdot 1^{n-k} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^k = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n (n-1) \ldots (n-k+1)}{k!} \cdot \frac{1}{n^k} \\[1ex]
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right) \ldots \left( 1 - \frac{k-1}{n} \right) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \cdot P_n^{(k)}
\end{align*}$$

where

$$P_n^{(k)} = \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right) \ldots \left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right).$$

We can see that for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $0 \leqslant P_n^{(k)} \leqslant 1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} P_n^{(k)} = 1$.

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $K$ be so large that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^K \frac{1}{k!} \geqslant (1-\varepsilon)S$. Now let $N$ be so large that whenever $n \geqslant N$, for $k = 0, 1, \ldots, K$ we have $P_n^{(k)} > 1-\varepsilon$.

So for $n \geqslant N$

$$\begin{align*}
(1-\varepsilon)^2 S \leqslant (1-\varepsilon) \sum_{k=0}^K \frac{1}{k!} \leqslant \sum_{k=0}^K \frac{1}{k!} P_n^{(k)} \leqslant \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \leqslant \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \leqslant S.
\end{align*}$$

Therefore

$$e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}.$$

Answer (score 2):

For me during calculus, the steps were:

1. Define $e$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$
2. Define $\ln x$ as the inverse function to $e^x$.
3. Prove that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln x = \frac1x$
4. From 3, prove that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$
5. Prove that, if a function $f$ is infinitly differentiable, then $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$ plus an error term which goes to $0$ in a lot of cases (including $e^x$).
6. From $5$, conclude that $$e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
7. Plug in $x=1$ into (6).

Comment: Can it be done without passing through continuous functions?

Comment: This way seems pretty neat though... :)

Comment: @0inegue Probably... I just don't know exactly how.